# How will Heroku's AMQP work?

Tags: heroku, amqp

I saw that they soon will have an addon for AMQP.

I'm about to learn how to use AMQP with RabbitMQ. I suppose that that addon doesn't deal with RabbitMQ.

Isn't AMQP just a protocol. Are they using any AMQP broker like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku founder has written a Ruby library named Minion https://github.com/orionz/minion that mentions RabbitMQ so I suspect that will be the one.

As long as they are using AMQP .8 and .9 then they will have to supply a broker. Only AMQP 1.0 can be used brokerless.